# How to get app crash details on android device (own unity app)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, exception, crash, apk

I made an app in Unity. The **WebGL** version works fine, but a problem is on Android. The build of the Android version works fine, but when I launch the app installed on my phone (**samsung galaxy s8**) the app crashes after the unity logo screen. Is there any possibility to get the error name that make the crash? When I use **Unity Remote 5** app on android for tests, then the app works fine.

Comment: What is your unity version?

Comment: 2019.3.6f1 personal is my unity version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android Logcat Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat@1.1/manual/index.html) is a utility for displaying log messages coming from Android device in Unity Editor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Comment: It works as I wanted, thank you. By the way the reason of my error was that I forgot to remove first scene from my WebGL version and the scene was some kind of lock from Crazy Games :p